# Row locking in oracle table with no rows selected

Tags: sql, oracle

If I am running a `SELECT ……. FOR UPDATE` query on a table in oracle for which no row is returned still a row level lock is created. For example if the below query is executed no record is returned because there is no value of object_key which has a value of ‘xxx’ in the table.

```
select * from payment_detail where object_key = 'xxx' for update;
```

However after the query is executed there is a row level lock created in the table PAYMENT_DETAIL as confirmed by querying the table `v$locked_object`. Could you please suggest how a row level lock is created in this scenario (when no record is getting returned by the query)

Answer (score 4):

It is a **3 - ROW_X (SX): Row Exclusive Table Lock**

Here is a demonstration :

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t AS
  2    SELECT LEVEL COL
  3    FROM   dual
  4    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM   t
  3  WHERE  col = 20
  4  FOR UPDATE;

no rows selected

SQL>
SQL> SELECT object_id,
  2         session_id,
  3         process,
  4         locked_mode
  5  FROM   v$locked_object;

 OBJECT_ID SESSION_ID PROCESS                  LOCKED_MODE
---------- ---------- ------------------------ -----------
     92549         12 9012:6928                          3

SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> SELECT object_id,
  2         session_id,
  3         process,
  4         locked_mode
  5  FROM   v$locked_object;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

#### More information whether other sessions can execute DML with existing Row Exclusive Table Lock

**Session 1:**

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM   t
  3  WHERE  col = 20
  4  FOR UPDATE;

no rows selected

SQL>
SQL> SELECT object_id,
  2         session_id,
  3         process,
  4         locked_mode
  5  FROM   v$locked_object;

 OBJECT_ID SESSION_ID PROCESS                  LOCKED_MODE
---------- ---------- ------------------------ -----------
     92551        124 8784:7948                          3
```

**Session 2:** Update the table

```
SQL> update t set col = 20 where col = 10;

1 row updated.
```

**Session 1:**

```
SQL> SELECT object_id,
  2         session_id,
  3         process,
  4         locked_mode
  5  FROM   v$locked_object;

 OBJECT_ID SESSION_ID PROCESS                  LOCKED_MODE
---------- ---------- ------------------------ -----------
     92551          7 8036:1680                          3
     92551        124 8784:7948                          3
```

**Session 2:** Issues commit

```
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

**Session 1:**

```
SQL> select * from t;

       COL
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6
         7
         8
         9
        20

10 rows selected.

SQL> SELECT object_id,
  2         session_id,
  3         process,
  4         locked_mode
  5  FROM   v$locked_object;

 OBJECT_ID SESSION_ID PROCESS                  LOCKED_MODE
---------- ---------- ------------------------ -----------
     92551        124 8784:7948                          3

SQL>
```

So, the session_id 7 is now released from the lock. You can see the object_id that it is same table locked in all the cases.

So, yes other sessions **can update**, since you don't have any rows locked for update.

But, if any rows are returned by the SELECT..FOR UPDATE, then those rows will be exclusively locked, and other sessions cannot do any DML on those rows and will keep waiting, until the previous session has committed or rolled back the changes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: To be honest, I don't think this answers the question. You're just demonstrating that the lock is created without explaining why.

Comment: So unless this session releases, no other session can update it?

Comment: Yes other sessions can update, since you don't have any rows locked for update. See my demo above, i have added more information.

Comment: You mean to say that if there is no rows with col=20 and a Row Exclusive lock is put on the table due to `for Update`, one can insert a record with col=20 into this table from another session?

Comment: @San, Yes other session can insert in this case. And until the other session commits the insert, you will see the Row Exclusive Table Lock for the other session. But, if there are any rows really locked for update, then the session session will keep waiting until the previous session holding the for update lock is committed or rolled back.

Comment: @Frank Schmitt, hope now the question is completely answered.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Much better :-)

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Lalit Kumar B's answer, using his example:

```
CREATE TABLE t AS
  SELECT LEVEL col
  FROM   dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
/

Table created.

SELECT *
FROM   t
WHERE  col = 20
FOR UPDATE;
/

no rows selected

SELECT xidusn,
       xidslot,
       xidsqn,
       object_id,
       session_id,
       locked_mode
FROM v$locked_object
/

    XIDUSN    XIDSLOT     XIDSQN  OBJECT_ID SESSION_ID LOCKED_MODE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         0          0          0     777950        130           3

SELECT sid,
       type,
       id1,
       id2,
       lmode,
       request,
       ctime,
       block
FROM   v$lock
WHERE  sid = 130
/

       SID TYPE        ID1        ID2      LMODE    REQUEST      CTIME      BLOCK
---------- ---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       130 AE          100          0          4          0       2771          0 
       130 TM       777950          0          3          0        582          0
```

The query against v$locked_object indicates that the table is locked in Locked Mode 3 (i.e. Row Exclusive Mode). Since the XIDUSN, XIDSLOT and XIDSQN are all 0 this indicates that no rows are actually locked.

This can be confirmed by the query against v$lock. Ignoring the AE lock, there is a TM Lock/Enqueue on the table, to prevent structural changes to the table during the transaction. This is in Locked Mode 3 (i.e. Row Exclusive Mode). But there are no TX Locks/Enqueues at row level.

This can be compared with:

```
ROLLBACK
/

Rollback complete.

SELECT *
FROM   t
WHERE  col = 1
FOR UPDATE;
/
       COL
----------
         1

SELECT xidusn,
       xidslot,
       xidsqn,
       object_id,
       session_id,
       locked_mode
FROM v$locked_object
/

    XIDUSN    XIDSLOT     XIDSQN  OBJECT_ID SESSION_ID LOCKED_MODE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         6         31     938022     777950        130           3 

SELECT sid,
       type,
       id1,
       id2,
       lmode,
       request,
       ctime,
       block
FROM   v$lock
WHERE  sid = 130
/

       SID TYPE        ID1        ID2      LMODE    REQUEST      CTIME      BLOCK
---------- ---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       130 AE          100          0          4          0       3315          0 
       130 TM       777950          0          3          0         61          0 
       130 TX       393247     938022          6          0         61          0
```

The query against v$locked_object again indicates that the table is locked in Locked Mode 3 (i.e. Row Exclusive Mode). However, since the XIDUSN, XIDSLOT and XIDSQN are all non 0 this indicates that rows are also locked.

This can be confirmed by the query against v$lock. Again, there is a TM Lock/Enqueue on the table, to prevent structural changes to the table during the transaction in Locked Mode 3 (i.e. Row Exclusive Mode). There are also TX Lock/Enqueues in Locked Mode 6 (Exclusive Mode) so the row returned for update cannot be modified by other users.

In conclusion. Once you issue DML to modify rows in a table, or issue a SELECT...FOR UPDATE indicating your intention to modify rows in a table, Oracle will first take a Row Exclusive Mode lock at the table level to ensure that no DDL is issued to structurally change the table. It will additionally Exclusively lock each row that has been modified. If no rows are modified no row level locks will be taken but the table level lock will still exist and not be released. It will not be released as under a two-phase locking protocol locks are only released during the commit or rollback phase.